# <Response [404]> Scraping data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this website [1xbet](https://1xbet.com/sports/basketball/early) but I'm getting this error <Response [404]> all the time.
Here is my code.

```
type here
import requests, bs4

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
url = "https://1xbet.com/sports/basketball/early"
response = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}, verify=False)

print(response)


# soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
# lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="a_event")

# print(lists)
```

How can I solve this?

I tried to include the headers and veriy=False so that it won't have the error "certificate verify failed", but after doing that I got this response 404. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

404 mean this url source not found,you need check the url is right

Comment: the url I embedded is the same as the url to get the data in my code, so I don't think that the url is the problem here :(

Comment: @kien enter this url in browser, use F12 open dev tools, I found a 307 redirect response,if you certain this url is right, maybe the website have some way to defend web spider,then you need create a 'human like' request,include headers, cookies, user-agent,etc...

Comment: Access to this website is prohibited in the United States.  I'm sure they are blocking web scrapers.  You might have better luck using Selenium to download the data you are looking for